# ASP timer blocking UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I've got a fairly simple asp.net page, with several buttons and textboxes etc whose visibility switches based on the results of queries.  Everything works fine.  But I got a request to embed a clock that shows server time continuously (this is essentially a timeclock web app).  I've followed several tutorials and examples online, and no matter what I do the timer seems to block things like button click events or textbox visibility etc.

For example, I found this on another SO thread:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <!-- your content here, no timer -->
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

And inserted my label, which showed the time inside the content template and updated it on the tick event.  Worked great, except for blocking my UI.

Most recent attempt was taken straight from a Telerik demo:
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajaxmanager/application-scenarios/ajaxify-timer/defaultcs.aspx

The timer itself works fine, just the interference with my UI that's a problem.

Edit to add page markup:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <link id="Link1" href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="True">

    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" >
        <AjaxSettings>

            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadButton1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton1" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="InButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OutButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="MessagePlaceholder" />

                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="InBtn">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="IDtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="PINtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton1" />
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="InButtonPlaceholder" />                    
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OutButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" />                    
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="AlertPlaceholder" />

                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="OutBtn">
                <UpdatedControls>

                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="IDtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="PINtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton1" />
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="InButtonPlaceholder" />                  
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OutButtonPlaceholder" />
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" />

                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="AlertPlaceholder" />

                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="StartBreakBtn">
                <UpdatedControls>

                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="IDtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="PINtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton1" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="InButtonPlaceholder" />
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OutButtonPlaceholder" />

                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" />

                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="EndBreakBtn">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="IDtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="PINtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton1" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="InButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OutButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ConfirmBtn">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="IDtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="PINtextbox" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="InButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OutButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="MessagePlaceholder" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>          
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="CloseNoticeButton">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="AlertPlaceholder" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>          
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

   <div style="text-align:center">
        <asp:TextBox ID="IDtextbox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
            Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Employee Number"></asp:Label>
           <asp:TextBox ID="PINtextbox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
            Font-Size="Large" MaxLength="4" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Enter PIN"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />


        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="PINtextbox" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" 
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" Display="Dynamic" 
            ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="IDtextbox" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" 
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" Display="Dynamic" 
            ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Log In" 
            onclick="RadButton1_Click" Height="75px" Width="200px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large" ValidationGroup="1" >
        </telerik:RadButton> 

    </div>

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="InButtonPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <telerik:RadButton ID="InBtn" runat="server" Text="Punch In"   onclick="InBtn_Click" Height="75px" Width="200px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large" >

        </telerik:RadButton>
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="OutButtonPlaceholder" runat="server" >
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <telerik:RadButton ID="OutBtn" runat="server" Text="Punch Out"   onclick="OutBtn_Click" Height="75px" Width="200px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large" CssClass="LargeButton" >
         </telerik:RadButton>
         <telerik:RadButton ID="StartBreakBtn" runat="server" Text="Start Break"   onclick="StartBreakBtn_Click" Height="75px" Width="200px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large" CssClass="LargeButton" >       
        </telerik:RadButton>
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="EndBreakButtonPlaceholder" runat="server" 
       >
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <telerik:RadButton ID="EndBreakBtn" runat="server" Text="End Break"   onclick="EndBreakBtn_Click" Height="75px" Width="200px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large" >
         </telerik:RadButton> 
         </div>       
    </asp:PlaceHolder><br /><br />
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="MessagePlaceholder" runat="server">
      <div style="text-align:center; border:medium solid red;padding:20px">
      <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="ConfirmBtn" runat="server" Text="I have read this message"   onclick="ConfirmBtn_Click" Height="75px" Width="550px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large"  AutoPostBack="True">
         </telerik:RadButton>
         </div>        
    </asp:PlaceHolder >
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="AlertPlaceholder" runat="server">
      <div style="text-align:center; border:medium solid red;padding:20px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Note!  This is outside your scheduled working hours and may be subject to review by management!"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
          <telerik:RadButton ID="CloseNoticeButton" runat="server" Text="OK" Height="75px" Width="200px" 
            Font-Size="XX-Large"   onclick="CloseNoticeButton_Click" CausesValidation="False">
          </telerik:RadButton>
        </div></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="text-align:center">
   <img alt="" src="Images/LgCentralLogo.png" "width:250px height:auto" 
            width="250px" />
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: If you're really just looking to display the time, why not do it in JavaScript? Server controls are much too heavy for this kind of functionality IMO

Comment: Because the timestamp is obtained from the server and they want to display the time as it will be recorded...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to overcome this issue:

**1.** Ensure there are no hidden script errors. Sometimes, script errors cause the UI controls stop functioning. [Details](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/ajaxmanager/details/get-more-descriptive-errors-by-disabling-ajax)

**2.** The benefit of AJAX is partial updating. Make sure that the timer updates only the related part of the page, e.g. Label and nothing else.

**3.** If you have scripts in the `<head>` tag, transfer them to the `<body>` after the script manager definition.

**4.** Wrap the timer inside an asp:Panel and use this panel. Also, you can add the panel to update itself:

```
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Panel1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" />
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Label1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Output"></asp:Label>
```

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    }
```

**5.** Useful hint - if the user has scrolled somewhere on the page and AJAX request occurs at that time, the scroll position will reset and automatically scroll to the top of the page. To prevent that, you can use this approach: [Source](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-you-prevent-browser-scrolling-after-ajax-postback#Bki1UISTeU6Z0MCtGgUZjA)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_beginRequest(function() {
        prm._scrollPosition = null;
    });
</script>
```

**6.** If you have custom scripts added dynamically on the code-behind, you can check [Demo 1](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajaxpanel/application-scenarios/persisting-javascript/defaultcs.aspx) and [Demo 2](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajaxpanel/application-scenarios/recreate-scripts/defaultcs.aspx) to see how you can recreate these scripts after AJAX request.

**7.** Wrap your script content within a [RadScriptBlock](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajaxmanager/radcodeblock-and-radscriptblock).

Comment: Thank you but same thing... if you're inclined to take a look, I added my page markup.  I tried your suggestions as well as many other examples online and they all exhibit the same behavior. :(